# is there a way to create fragment from a activty-adapter imagebutton?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-adapter

i need to create a fragment from activty-adapter on imagebutton click and to pass 3 data along

having trouble with fragment or it says
android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity

please help someone
code is in the image

[code i tried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbAPx.png)

Comment: It is best to post the code in the question itself rather than have an image.  We have no idea what `TimeLineAdapter` is, a Recylcer Adapter?  But it is not an `Activity`.  So when you call 
`((Activity) context)` it fails to cast as an Activity.  

If you want the adapter to communicate with the activity, you need a listener in the adapter - an interface, or possibly a lambda passed in to the item in the list itself that you can just call.

Comment: yes...its a recycler adapter within an activity

Comment: im having trouble with adding code with the post.........can you able to give me a default solution to create a fragment from a adapter,just like the image

Comment: You really need to figure out how to post code, that is important for stack overflow!  We don't even know what `holder.commenting` is .

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do it (although you should probably communicate through a viewModel, that is beyond scope of this question):

First take in a listener into the adapter

```
class FakeAdapter(private val items: List<String>, private val startFragmentCallback: () -> Unit) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<FakeViewHolder>() {
```

Then, in the onBindViewHolder:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: FakeViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener { // in your case this might be holder.commenting - but i don't know what 'commenting' is
            startFragmentCallback.invoke()
        }
    }
```

Then in the Activity have a private function to create the fragment:

```
private fun startFragmentCallback() {
        // code to start fragment goes here
    }
```

And then use that function when creating your adapter in the activity:

```
 val listOfStrings = listOf("1", "2", "3")
 val adapter = FakeAdapter(listOfStrings, this::startFragmentCallback)
```